# Python typing annotations in try/except blocks

Tags: python, annotations, mypy

I don't understand why mypy is complaining about wrong type in one of my methods:

```
    def check_earliest(self, symbol: str) -> Optional[datetime]:
        """Return earliest date of available data for a given symbol."""
        try:
            return self.read(symbol).index.min()
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            return None
```

The error is:

> Item "None" of "Optional[Any]" has no attribute "index"

I accept that *self.read(symbol)* may return *None* and then trying to access *index* attribute on it would result in *AttributeError*. But that's exactly why I put it in a try/except block in line with *It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission*.

Then why is it an error?

Comment: The problem lies with `self.read()`. Show us its signature.

Comment: The type checker is doing exactly what it's supposed to, which is prevent you from assuming that `self.read(symbol)` does *not* return `None`. The `try` block is a *runtime* construct, and the type checker (pretends that it) doesn't know that the attempt to access the attribute `index` will produce an `AttributeError` that will be caught and handled.

Comment: For that matter, even a value of type `Any` may not have an `index` attribute: you'll need to use `typing.cast` to tell the type checker that *you* know that `index` is OK (or at least you are prepared to handle the consequences when it isn't).

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand what you're saying but still find it hard to accept. Using try/except blocks for code that we know may produce errors is an established pattern in python. Mypy is supposed to make life easier, here it's making it unnecessarily difficult. I'll probably just add `# type: ignore` for this line.

Comment: Signature of `self.read()` is: `def read(self, symbol: Union[str, Contract], *args, **kwargs) -> Optional[pd.DataFrame]:`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it like this

```
def check_earliest(self, symbol: str) -> Optional[SomeType]:
        """Return earliest date of available data for a given symbol."""
        try:
            data = self.read(symbol) # data is Optional[SomeType] and have't index attr
            if data: # Check data is not None
                return data.index.min() # and here linter knows what type it is
            
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            return None
```

Or if yours python version >=3.8, like this:

```
def check_earliest(self, symbol: str) -> Optional[SomeType]:
        """Return earliest date of available data for a given symbol."""
        try:
            if data := self.read(symbol):
                return data.index.min()
            
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            return None
```

This is because Optional[SomeType] object must be checked in if expression to let linter knows what it is.

Comment: Yes, this will work, thank you. But I guess my question was broader: am I missing something or is mypy complaining about perfectly correct python code?

Comment: @t1user https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8056

Comment: that explains everything. Thanks!